# how to get server adress ip dynamiclly in java

Tags: java, android, ip, server

I'm trying to develop a new android application (java) in localhost, and i want to allow to the user to put his server address ip in the application after i deploy the application.
here's the connection methode

```html
public class connexiondb {
 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
 protected Connection getConnection(){
  StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy=new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
  StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
  Connection conn=null;
        String connURL;
        try {
   Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
   connURL="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=idmaj;user=youssef;password=azerty" ;
   conn=DriverManager.getConnection(connURL);    
   //conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
   Log.e("ERROR",e.getMessage());
  }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
   Log.e("ERROR",e.getMessage());
  }catch (Exception e) {
   Log.e("ERROR",e.getMessage());
  }
        return conn;
 }

}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i want to allow to the user to put his server address ip in the application after i deploy the application.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a config file where you persist the ip. 
Provide a screen where the user can input the URI and persist in your config file. 
When instantiating the client, read the config file for the new URI.